# SQL Server table daily sync of records from table A to table B

Tags: sql-server, azure-data-factory

I want to create a daily process where I reload all rows from table A into table B.  Over time table A rows will change due to changes in source system and also because of aging/deletion of records in the origin table.  Table A gets truncated/reloaded daily in step 1.  Table B is the master table that just gets new/updated rows.

From a historical point of view, I want to keep track of ALL the rows in table B and be able to do a point in time comparison for analytics purposes.

So I need to do two things, Daily insert rows from table A to table B if they don't exist and then also create a new record in Table B if the record already exists but ANY of the columns have changed. At one point I attempted to use temporal tables but I had too many false/positives on 'real' changes, basically certain columns were throwing off things because a date/time column was updated(only real change in row).

I'm using a Azure SQL Server Managed Instance database (Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8).
At my disposal I have SSMS, SQL Server and also Azure Data Factory.

Any suggestions on the best way to do this or tools to help with this?

Comment: Have you looked at Change Tracking?

Comment: I was taking a look at CDC (changed data capture) but hadn't tried it out.

Comment: I've used CDC for extracting data for analysis in a DW scenario, it will certainly meet your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 concepts out of which you can implement any one.

1. Temporal table
2. Capture Data Change (CDC)

As CDC is the commonly used approach in which you can create an **Azure data factory** with a **pipeline** that loads delta data based on change data capture (CDC) information in the source **Azure SQL Managed Instance database** to an **Azure blob storage**.

To implement the CDC, you can you can follow this simple Microsoft tutorial [Incrementally load data from Azure SQL Managed Instance to Azure Storage using change data capture (CDC)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-incremental-copy-change-data-capture-feature-portal)

Note: You also need to [Create a storage account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-account-create?tabs=azure-portal) which is required but not given in above tutorial.